# I got an error: Package 'tabbar-20160524' is a system package,not deleting

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, tabbar

I installed spacemacs using "git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs.git ~/spacemacs/.emacs.d"
but I got an error:  Package 'tabbar-20160524' is a system package,not deleting....[image]

When I started emacs with --debug-init I got this:[image]

but I am not good at elisp, this error is difficult for me , can you help me solve it, thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) Can you paste in the text of your error messages please? The screenshots are hard to read for me (and the text will make your question easier to search for)

Comment: related unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803756/cant-load-spacemacs-its-trying-to-delete-pspp-mode

Comment: I suspect a bug somewhere deep in spacemacs's `configuration-layer/sync` - check for a spacemacs update. Either that or spacemacs is not compatible with your version of Emacs

Comment: What happens when you try `M-x package-delete` `tabbar-20160524`? (Which by the way is a pretty old version of tabbar. That suggests to me that someone has already customized your Emacs before you installed spacemacs.) Where did you get Emacs, what version is it, and what OS do you run?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for a lot of packages that I tried to remove. I'm not sure, but it might be because I had an older version of Emacs, so maybe the newer version had problems when trying to remove a bunch of packages installed from an older version.

The workaround I did (thanks to [@dcorking's comment above](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55192/i-got-an-error-package-tabbar-20160524-is-a-system-package-not-deleting#comment86396_55192)) was to use `M-x package-delete` for each package, and then it told me that the package was a dependency for another package, so then I used `M-x package-delete` to delete the other package and was then able to delete the dependency package afteward.

UPDATE: that only worked for a few packages then stopped working. It looks like my actual problem was that I am using Windows with a unicode character in my HOME path, which causes a number of problems in Emacs, so to workaround the problem, I had to tell Emacs to use a different HOME directory (see [this Emacs doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html)). I created a `C:\.emacs` that is a symlink to `%APPDATA%\.emacs.d\init.el` and also made a directory junction called `C:\.emacs.d` that points to `%APPDATA%\.emacs.d`.